# Python syntax error: can't assign to operator in module but works in interpreter

Tags: python, syntax

I have a string `a` and I would like to split it in half depending on its length, so I have

```
a-front = len(a) / 2 + len(a) % 2
```

this works fine in the interpreter but when i run the module from the command line python gives me a `SyntaxError: can't assign to operator`. What could be the issue here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might mistype hyphen and underscore, try

```
a_front = len(a) / 2 + len(a) % 2
```