# special character handling in python (hyphen (-))

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql

Hi I am trying to import a csv file in Pyspark which has fields having Hyphen symbol in between like education-num and marital-status etc.

I need to define my schema for this file, where the columns name should be same as above field name.
 I use the below codes for it:

```
ageType=StructField('age', IntegerType(),True)
workclassType=StructField('workclass', StringType(),True)
```

Success

Where it works But when i try below one it fails:

```
education-numType=StructField('education\-num',DoubleType(),True)

File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

Possible ways to handle this.

Comment: You can't have hyphens in variable names in python. That's the subtraction operator. Consider using an underscore instead: `education_numType = ...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python syntax error: can't assign to operator in module but works in interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697610/python-syntax-error-cant-assign-to-operator-in-module-but-works-in-interpreter)